# How to render a list with data from inside a function using React?

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, reactjs, web-applications

[Source Code](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/KanteLabs/KanteCloud/master/src/components/SearchBar.js)

Sorry if the title is confusing. But if you click on the source code you can see that I have a component name Search. Inside search is a function `handleSearchSubmit` that activates when a user clicks the search button inside of the render function. Now my issue is that I want to now update the list inside `trackViewer`. Every list item should be populated with a `{title}` and the `<ul>` should be called `{trackItems}`. But whatever I do I can seem to get the list to update. If I do not include `this` then the variable t`rackItems` is undefined inside the render function. So what exactly am I doing wrong? Should this be separate component inside the same file or a new file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, the desired behaviour here is to fetch data from an API and display it when it is received.
It's important to realise the fundamental idea of React. The component will re-render if and only if the it's state or upstream props change. Which is what you need here. Use state change to trigger re-render.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { client_id } from './config';
import 'isomorphic-fetch';
import 'whatwg-fetch';
import SC from 'soundcloud';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

// This is not a good place for such data, all data should be encapsulated accordingly
let search = "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks?&client_id="+ client_id +"&limit=50&offset=0&q="+query;
let tags = "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks?linked_partitioning=1&client_id="+ client_id +"&limit=50&offset=0&tags=deep%20house";

class Search extends Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            value: '',
            // Moved trackTitle from above into the state
            trackTitle: []
        };
    };

    handleChange(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
    }

    handleSearchSubmit(){
        event.preventDefault();

        // Create local scope buffer for trackTitles to store in state in the end
        let trackTitleBuffer = []

        // You can use shortened expression instead of client_id: client_id, hail ES2015!
        SC.initialize({ client_id });

        // You don't really need query variable, use state directly
        // Using arrow functions for readability
        fetch(search + this.state.value, { method:"GET" })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
        .then(json => {
            json.map(entity => trackTitleBuffer.push(entity.title))
           // And pour it all to the state.trackTitle
           // This is important, you only to want to re-render when you have all the track titles ready
           // If you pushed the track titles to the state one-by-one, every push would trigger a re-render
           // It might look cool as well as it might not
            this.setState({ trackTitle: trackTitleBuffer })
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
    };

    render(){
        // Desctructuring the state
        const { trackTitle, value } = this.state

        return(
            <form>
            <input type="text" value={this.state.value} placeholder="Enter a Artist, Song, or Album.." onChange={event => this.handleChange(event)}/>
            <button type="button" onClick={() => this.handleSearchSubmit()}>Search</button>
            <div id="trackViewer">
                 <p>Results for: {value}</p>
                 <ul>{ trackTitle.map(title => <li key={title)}>{title}</li>) }</ul>
            </div>
            </form>
        )
    };
};

export default Search;
```

Comment: Thank you this solution solved both the rerendering and the listing issues. .

Answer (score 0):

Your trackItems variable is a local variable not attached to your class, so you can't access it through this.trackItems inside your render function

```
const trackItems = trackTitle.map((titles) =>
            <li>{titles}</li>
        );
```

So a quick fix, do away with the trackItems variable completely and instead run that code snippet inside your render function as is:

```
render(){
    return(
        <form>
        <input type="text" value={this.state.value} placeholder="Enter a Artist, Song, or Album.." onChange={this.handleChange}/>
        <button type="button" onClick={this.handleSearchSubmit}>Search</button>
        <div id="trackViewer">
             <p>Results for: {this.state.value}</p>
             <ul>{trackTitle.map((titles) =><li>{titles}</li>)}</ul>
        </div>
        </form>
    )
}
```

Comment: I updated the code so you can see it as well, but I tried what you suggested and nothing is still being displayed. In the console I can see that the values are empty so something should be displayed.

Comment: I was actually able to get it to work but there is a weird bug occurring. Where the list actually doesn't display the results until I click on the input and type something in. I suspect this might be because it is inside the form tag